# Simple + Artinian = Semiprimitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, rngs

By a noncommutative ring I mean that it has **no** unit.

I know that if some ring (say, $R$) is simple, then:

1. $R^2 \neq (0)$
2. It only possesses $2$ two-sided ideals, namely $(0)$, and itself.

And that, the Jacobson ideal of $R$ is a two-sided ideal of it. So it can either be $0$, or $R$. Now that I want to prove $R$ is semiprimitive, i.e., I have to prove $J(R) = 0$, i.e. to prove that $J(R) \neq R$ (Herstein's book defines $J(R)$ to be $R$ if there's no maximal regular right ideal of $R$), or, in other words, what I need to prove is there exists some maximal regular right ideal of $R$. How can I use the fact that $R$ is Artinian to do so?

Thank you guys very much,

Have a good day, :*

Comment: The rng $R=2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ appears to be a counterexample to this, though. It's clearly Artinian, simple, and $rad(R)=R$. Are you leaving out some conditions? Something like $R^2\neq 0$ would rule this example out, but I don't know if that's the missing condition or not. Did you find this problem somewhere or is it your own exploration? It would be good to include the source you found it in.

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm sorry. It's a quote from Herstein's noncomutative algebra book, on page 33, what exactly it says is: "We leave to the reader to show that a simple Artinian ring must be semisimple" (but his definition of semisimple is actually semiprimitive). And he defines simple ring as $R^2 \neq 0$, plus the fact that it has only 2 ideals (0), and $R$. I'll edit it now, sorry.

Comment: «By a noncommutative ring I mean that it has no unit» is a very strange convention! How do you say, then, that the ring is not commutative?

Comment: I don't know, maybe unitary noncommutative ring. It's the author's convention, noncommutative ring = no unit + the operation (*) is not commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very early on page $8$ in *Noncommutative Rings* (also by Herstein), the author notes that irreducible (which I'm reading as 'simple') right $R$ modules all have the form $R/K$ where $K$ is a maximal *and regular* right ideal. I imagine he includes something similar in the text you are reading.

The Artinian condition, along with $R^2\neq \{0\}$, gives us the existence of simple right $R$ modules (in the form of minimal right ideals).

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Cool, I get it now, thank you so much. :*